# How to get the name of a layer without loading it into a map with ArcGIS Pro 3.1 API?

Tags: c#, arcgis, add-on

In my ArcGIS Pro-Addon I want to load a .lyr-File into a map but only if it is not already loaded. This is the code I used in ArcGIS-Desktop:

```
public static void LoadDataToArcMap(String layerfilename)
{
    IGxLayer pGxLayer = new GxLayerClass();
    IGxFile pGxFile = (IGxFile)pGxLayer;
    pGxFile.Path = layerfilename;

    IMxDocument doc = ArcMap.Document;
    IMap map = doc.FocusMap;
    Int16 index = 0;
    if (map.LayerCount > 0)
    {
        do
        {

            ILayer layer = map.get_Layer(index);
            index++;
            if (layer.Name == pGxLayer.Layer.Name)
                return;
        }
        while (index < map.LayerCount);
    }
    map.AddLayer(pGxLayer.Layer);
}
```

But with the new API I dont find a way to get the name of the Layer (which can be different from the filename) without loading it into my map.

```
private static void LoadLayer(string layerFilename)
{

    Map map = MapView.Active.Map;
    

    //I already tried this but createParams.Item.Name is empty
    //var uriNewLayer = new Uri(layerFilename);
    //var createParams = new LayerCreationParams(uriNewLayer);
    //var newLayerName = createParams.Item.Name;
    
    var newLayerName = "???";

    foreach (var layer in map.Layers)
    {
        if (layer.Name == newLayerName)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Layer '" + newLayerName + "' already loaded.");
            return;
        }
    }
  
    Layer newLayer = LayerFactory.Instance.CreateLayer(uriNewLayer, map);
}
```

Comment: Did you read this: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/sdk/api-reference/topic26514.html? I supsect you need to get the `CIMLayerDocument ` by calling `GetCIMLayerDocument` on your `LayerDocument`. From there go to the `CIMDefinition[i].Name`.

Comment: I already tried: var layerDoc = new LayerDocument(); but it throws an excaption (cant get encoding). I suspect this is because my layer is a .lry-File instead of a .lyrx-File. But Ill try it once again. I might got something wrong.

Comment: Aaah, I don't know if the SDK can read a lyr-file out of the box. I assume you need to load it into Pro and save it as lyrx-file once.

Comment: Is there a way to get the filename of a loaded layer (I didnt find one)? If there is I could compare the filenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the ArcGIS Pro 3.1 API seems not to be able to read a Layername directly from a .lyr-file. So I use this function as a provisional solution:

```
    private static string GetLayerName(string layerFilename)
    {
        Map tempmap = MapFactory.Instance.CreateMap("Temp");
        var uriNewLayer = new Uri(layerFilename);
        var createParams = new LayerCreationParams(uriNewLayer);
        createParams.IsVisible = false;
        var newLayerForName = LayerFactory.Instance.CreateLayer<Layer>(createParams, tempmap);
        var newLayerName = newLayerForName.Name;
        tempmap.RemoveLayer(newLayerForName);
        return newLayerName;
    }
```

I am not sure if I should somehow close or unload the temporary map (tempmap). I did not find a way to do so.